# Python on Autodesk construction cloud

Tags: python, autodesk, construction

Can anyone help with using python on Autodesk Constriction Cloud?
I'm having trouble obtaining the access token and even wirn an access token I can't call an endpoint because I get the error Resourse doesn't exist.

I got the token using Workato, and in Workato I can use the exact same endpoint to het the contents of a folder.

Thanks in advance